# DOORS DXL include in batchmode

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm trying to run a DXL Script in the DOORS-Batch Mode and I want to include a file with config-data when starting it via a batch file

```
set exePath=%cd%
cd "C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\"
doors -user "XXX" -password "YYY" -p %1 -b 
"Script.dxl" -dxl "#include <%exePath%>"
```

When I start DOORS in GUI-Mode I can execute the script, when I start it in the batchmode I get a weird error saying something like

DOORS: Assertion Failed, Line 436, ..., internal error

I cant find a solution, has anybody got a clue?

%exePath% is the path of the dxl file with the config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The \ in the string that you pass to -dxl, contained in your variable exePath are interpreted by DOORS as
   escape characters. When you give a path to a file, either use
   forward slashes (c:/my/dxl-dir) or double backward slashes
   (c:\\my\\dxl-dir).
2. Where is Script.dxl located? I assume it resides in the directory where the script is started. The #include command will read the content of a file and replace the #include command with the content. It is not used to tell DOORS where a script resides. For telling DOORS where a script resides, you can use registry settings, environment variables or the command line switches -addins (or -projectaddins or -layoutaddins).
3. If Script.dxl resides in the start directory, there is no need at all to to the "cd" at the top of your script. Just start "c:\program files....\bin\doors.exe -b Script.dxl
4. Not every script runs in batch mode. Anything that needs GUI functions, like Views, will not work

Comment: I think I found that the problem is in the include

when I try to include a variable it doesnt seem to work at all, I keep getting 

    -E- DXL: <Line:9> badly formed token (#include)

The #include is not interpreting the string but taking it as it comes, e.g. I try

const string abc = "hello"
#include <abc>

it's not interpreting the abc as "hello", it searches for a path named "abc" instead. 

Do you know how I can get variables to work in #include?

Comment: To refer to your answer: 
1. I've tried forward and double backslashes (%exePath:\=\\%)
2. the DXL script is generated in the folder of the bat, I think your approach is a nice workaround (I just generate the file in the DOORS path)
3. its not using any GUI functions

Comment: about the interperation of variables: you will have to prepare the string in dos and then send it to doors. e.g. 
set "sDXLScript=#include <%exePath%>"
... doors ... -dxl %sDXLScript%