Path for running batch mode in DOORs
When I try to use batch mode in doors with command line "-b abc.dxl", the path of .dxl file is set default in "C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.7".
How can I modify this path?
For example with (-b "expectingpath/abc.dxl"), it return
-F- DOORS: batch file 'C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.7\expectingpath/abc.dxl' not found
Press return to exit DOORS.

This https://stackoverflow.com/a/45216503/3329561 or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56167559/3329561 might help you.
In short: either change the path to the default directory (addins, projectaddins), cd to the base dir, or if you don't have includes, use e.g. a full path like -b "C:\\my\\path\\to\\file.dxl"

Thank you for responding @Mike,
But if I use the full path like you mentioned, the cmd return:
-F- DOORS: batch file 'C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.7\C:\my\path\to\file.dxl' not found
Press return to exit DOORS.
Maybe because the path for running batch mode is configured to "C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.7" and I don't really know how can I modify this path.

you might want to give it a 2nd try by using single backslashes or forward slashes. But if this all does not work for you then your DOORS system administrators have disabled overriding the doors path, probably in order to prevent illegal activities. you might have to contact them.
